# Erro no convert_from() | SQL_ASCII

Tags: postgresql, codificação-de-caracteres

Ao tentar utilizar a função `convert_from` do **postgresql** estou me deparando com o seguinte erro:

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0x30 0x30
```

Já procurei aqui no stack e não encontrei nada que possa me ajudar.

Comment: Qual é o seu intento em utilizar a função `convert_from()` ? Tem uma amostra do dado de entrada ? Qual é a saída esperada ?

Comment: Tenho um arquivo .txt, pego ele como bytea, preciso ler esse arquivo e pegar algumas informações e salvar na base. Exemplo : convert_from(NEW.arquivo, 'SQL_ASCII'), me retorna um text sem caracteres especiais.

Comment: Qual é o `encoding` desse seu arquivo `.txt` ? Qual é o `encoding` do seu banco de dados ? Qual é o `encoding` da saída que recebe o conteúdo convertido retornado por `convert_from()` ?

Comment: @Lacobus Arquivo : ? ( Não tenho certeza, é gerado na maquina do cliente "WINDOWS" ) , DBA : UTF-8 , SAIDA : SQL_ASCII

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa identificar o `encoding` de todas as suas entradas e saídas para evitar confusões e não perder o dado original pelo caminho.

Em primeiro lugar, você precisa identificar o `encoding` no qual o seu arquivo `.txt` foi gravado.

Em sistemas `*nix` você pode utilizar o utilitário `file` para detectar o `encoding` de um arquivo:

```
$ file entrada1.txt 
entrada1.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text

$ file entrada2.txt 
entrada2.txt: ISO-8859 text

$ file entrada3.txt 
entrada3.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Identificando o `encoding` de cada arquivo, você será capaz de converte-los adequadamente usando a função `convert_from()`:

```
-- Lendo arquivo UTF-8/UNICODE
SELECT convert_from( pg_read_binary_file( 'entrada1.txt' ), 'UTF8' );

-- Lendo arquivo LATIN-1 / ISO-8859-1
SELECT convert_from( pg_read_binary_file( 'entrada2.txt' ), 'LATIN1' );

-- Lendo arquivo puramente ASCII
SELECT convert_from( pg_read_binary_file( 'entrada3.txt' ), 'SQL_ASCII' );
```